# jQuery .load in wordpress (open link in new tab trouble)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

The way I have it set up, it works just fine, the only problem is if a user right clicks and opens the link in a new tab it's pretty much a styleless html document with content on it (since I had to remove the  from every template so that it didn't double it on each page.

Like I said, it's fine the way it is, but it really bothers me because I know some users will definitely open link in new tab and see it.

And before you tell me to remove the load function (which is how I had it before), I must have it because there is a radio on the header. I don't want it to refresh everytime somebody goes to a new page.

If I made any sense at all, can anyone help?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $(".link a").click(function(){
        var toLoad = $(this).attr("href")
        $(".new-body div").html("<center><div style='margin-top:20px;'><img src='http://habbolicious.com/wp-content/themes/habbolicious/images/loading.gif' /></div></center>");
        $(".new-body div").slideUp("slow").load(toLoad).slideDown('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

That's the jQuery, and here is the actual navigation:

```
              <div style="float:left; margin-top:16px; margin-right:20px;" class="link"><a href="/v1"><img src="http://habbolicious.com/wp-content/themes/habbolicious/images/logosmall.png" /></a></div>
          <div class="nav-home link"><a href="/staff">Staff</a></div>
          <div class="nav-news link"><a href="/news">News</a></div>
                    <div class="nav-events link"><a href="/events">Events</a></div>
          <div class="nav-values link"><a href="/rare-values">Rare Values</a></div>
          <div class="nav-forum link"><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></div>
          <div class="nav-forum"><a href="/forum"></a></div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. You are a genius! I never would have thought of that.

Comment: Posted a quick answer with some CSS :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than have a link, have a span styled as a link, that way right clicking will won't give the option to open in a new tab. Here's some sample CSS for it:

```
span {
    cursor:pointer;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: yeah, thanks again. i styled it up myself when you told me. that really helped out a lot. only problem now is, it seems like my pages are taking forever to load since .load() is having to load so much content. might just go back to normal.